# Can I flatten MariaDB general logs from their multiline format?

Tags: logging, mariadb

We're trying to get our MariaDB transaction logs imported into SumoLogic, however the logs are in a multiline format so the logs that are being uploaded are essentially unusable in this format. Sumo allows us to use regex to determine the log boundaries, however the logging is such that this is untenable. Is it possible to natively squash the multiline output into a single log entry?

Comment: I've had this challenge before.   Please provide a few _dissimilar_ examples, plus the programming language you would like to work with.

Comment: I was hoping that this was doable within MariaDB's settings. Given that you're asking for examples and a language I'd be working with, it sounds like it's not.
Thank you anyway

Comment: Not many _performance_ issues can be fixed by changes to the tunables.